# I cant access to about page when Im Authentified in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-blade, laravel-middleware

I have small problem that become big
well i have 4 pages

- about.blade.php  (everybody can access to this) home.blade.php
  (secure page needs authentification) login.blade.php
  register.blde.php

and i have layout : app.blade.php

my route.php is like that :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/about', 'AboutController@index');

Route::auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

my AboutController is like that :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class AboutController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {

    }

   public function index() {
        $data = 'some text from index page';
        return view('pages.about', compact('data'));
    }

}
```

my layout is like that :

```
            @if (Auth::gest())
                <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
            @else
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                        {{ Auth::user()->username }} <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/profile') }}">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/password') }}">Change password</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            @endif
```

the problem is here : i think Auth::gest() not work when im Authentified, 
when i put : $this->middleware('auth');  in the constructor of about, it works, but i want everbody access to this page.

i get this error im view, but in the html source code :

```
 <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">
                <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>
                                        <h2 class="block_exception clear_fix">
                            <span class="exception_counter">1/1</span>
                            <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException">FatalErrorException</abbr> in <a title="C:\wamp\www\laravel-lab\crud-app2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php line 314" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ClassLoader.php line 314</a>:</span>
                            <span class="exception_message">Maximum function nesting level of &#039;100&#039; reached, aborting!</span>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="block">
                            <ol class="traces list_exception">
       <li> in <a title="C:\wamp\www\laravel-lab\crud-app2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php line 314" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ClassLoader.php line 314</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException">FatalErrorException</abbr>->__construct() in <a title="C:\wamp\www\laravel-lab\crud-app2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php line 133" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">HandleExceptions.php line 133</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions">HandleExceptions</abbr>->fatalExceptionFromError() in <a title="C:\wamp\www\laravel-lab\crud-app2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php line 118" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">HandleExceptions.php line 118</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions">HandleExceptions</abbr>->handleShutdown() in <a title="C:\wamp\www\laravel-lab\crud-app2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php line 0" ondblclick="var f=this.inner
```

something like that, please any help ??

Thanks so much

Comment: looks like the error has something to do with Composer autoloader. Try running `composer dumpautoload`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo (there is no `gest()` method), so use `guest()` instead of `gest()`:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
```

Comment: I still have the problem, i tried also Auth::check()

Comment: Yes, but this is another problem. Please look in log at `/storage/logs/laravel.log` and tell me what exactly error do you get, then I'll be able to help you.

Comment: [2016-11-03 00:34:28] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!' in C:\wamp\www\laravel-lab\crud-app3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader.php:63
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\laravel-lab\crud-app3\vendor\laravel\fra................

Answer (score 0):

This is my AboutController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class AboutController extends Controller {
    public function __construct(){
       //$this->middleware('auth');
        //$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'index']);
    }
    public function index() {
        $data = 'Some data from About Controller';
        return view('pages.about', $data);
    }
```

}

my route is like that :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/about', 'AboutController@index');
```

I only add this AboutController After generate auth with php artisan make:auth

so when i try to access to http://localhost:8000/about i get the error like you must use middleware auth in this page too

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :)

I think its because my old version of PHP, I have PHP Version : 5.5.12.

I see that laravel require minimum on there website, so i change my PHP VERSION to 5.6.25 , and everything looks work fine :)